# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sameSite'

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

```
${my_cookie}=    Get Cookie    thecookie
```

Result:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sameSite'`

I have tried this with a few different cookies that have SameSite attribute. I was thinking if the casing matters but it is set as `SameSite` not `sameSite` as the error message indicates:

```
Set-Cookie: thecookie=testing;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 02-Jul-2020 13:38:09 GMT;Max-Age=25200;Secure;SameSite=None
```

I found this which is in fixed state:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3264

Chrome version: Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

ChromeDriver version: 83.0.4103.14 (Win32)

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary
```

solved the problem.